# Invalid pointer handling policy

Tags: c++, pointers

I think if null pointer passed in a function, just let it gp and we can find the root cause easily. But my teammate say we should avoid the gp times in production code, clients may be upset if application usually crash although the root cause may be covered in some null pointer protection.

Which method will you use when you need to validate the pointer is null?

```
HRESULT function(const int* pNumber)
{
    { POINTER CHECK for pNumber... }
    ...
}
```

**Method 1 - Ignore the invalid case**

```
if(pNumber)
{
    int a = *pNumber;   
}
```

- No GP
- Possible enter abnormal flow
- Hard to find root cause

**Method 2 - Assert pointer, warning in debug mode**

```
assert(pNumber);
int a = *pNumber;
```

- May GP in release mode
- Never enter abnormal flow
- Easy to find root cause

**Method 3 - Leave debug message and return error code**

```
if(!pNumber)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"Error Null pointer in function.\n");
    return E_POINTER;
}
```

- No GP
- Never enter abnormal flow inside the function. Client may enter abnormal flow out-side if he ignores E_POINTER returned
- Silently hard to find root cause

**Method 4 - Throw a logic_error exception - Let caller catch**

```
if(!pNumber)
{
    throw std::logic_error("Null pointer of pNumber in function");
};
```

- No GP
- Possible resource leak in code sequence without resource management(RAII) when stack is unwinding.
- Never enter abnormal flow
- Hard to find where the exception is throwed

Comment: General protection fault, it usually happens when you reference a invalid address or 0x00000000, then the application abort or crash immediately.

Comment: You question would improve if you uppercased the GP and at least mentioned it once what you want it to mean. That said, since you are using C++, it's obviously Method 5, pass a reference, which will force the caller to first validate their pointers.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You should make that an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dereference a `nullptr`, you enter the land of undefined behaviour. This means, your compiler isn't obliged to do [anything sensible](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), so this should really be avoided. It may also decide that since it is illegal, it never happened, so it removes the corresponding code (and thereby optimizing it) and you have logic errors without hitting a general protection fault.

I personally prefer the `assert`-case if a `nullptr` is absolutely invalid, but in that case a reference might be more sensible anyway. I don't think there is a general policy, because it depends heavily on the surrounding logic.

Answer (score 1):

Exception are a serious breach of contract, and this make sense if you have two modules which communicate via interface. Not so much for a static function local to a cpp unit to throw it. Think about accessing an array past the end. It also assume the other party will catch it.

None of the other are good enough alone.

- `assert(pNumber);` alone is weak. there might be a behavior which is
  specific to release mode and you will not catch it. Furthermore it is
  limited to the range of inputs you have tested in debug (which is far
  from all).
- Ignore the invalid case as shown above is plugin your head in the
  ground like an ostrich.
- `OutputDebugString` is weaker than assert. You the dev will eventually let
  things slide with error messages you will get used to so much you
  will stop reading them.

So If I am not using exceptions I will use

```
assert(pNumber);
if(pNumber)
{

}
else
{
   //Log with a logger which has different logging level to the level you seem fit 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I priffer Method 2

```
assert(pNumber);
int a = *pNumber;
```

because, In debug mode you can easily identify where the assert failure occured. even in release mode It assures null value will not continue in to the function inside. User will not see any abnormal behaviors and application would work as normal.

Comment: How does assert affect the program in release mode? I thought assert is removed in release mode.

Comment: There are no such things as "debug mode" and "release mode" in C++, they are MSVCisms. However, `assert()` is stripped if the macro `NDEBUG` is `#defined`, and this macro is often defined for optimized (non-debug) builds.